# C# how do I include the following in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I have a MVC website which uses razor syntax. I generate a table from values from a db. 
In a table cell I have some text e.g.
This is some text

code

```
<td>
 this is <b>some</b> text
</td>
```

Now I need a word to be bold. I have tried `<b>some</b>` but that is exactly how it appears on the web page. I need it to look like
This is **some** text

Comment: The way your code is in your example should work.  Is `<b>some</b>` coming from a database, and you are really rendering `<td>this is @someValue test</td>`?

Comment: <td>@somevalue</td>

Comment: Thought so!  In that case, `Html.Raw` should solve your problem.

Comment: Just one more thing. the code is currently @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].QuestionText)  should it be  @Html.Raw(Model[i].QuestionText)

Comment: If `Model[i].QuestionText` is just a string, then there's no reason to use `DisplayFor` anyway, which is typically used to render complex objects with more than one piece of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this could be happening is if your `<b>some</b>` string is coming from a variable elsewhere in your code.  Razor automatically escapes this for safety reasons, but you can force it to be rendered as-is with view helpers already available in Razor.

Use the [`Html.Raw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.111%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) helper to render a string without sanitizing it.

```
<td>
    This is @Html.Raw(Model[i].QuestionText) text
</td>
```